# Cost-based pricing in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to implement the following in my store, using Magento.

- Any product under £10 cost price will sell at RRP
- Any product above £10 cost price would be priced as follows – Cost Price + 69%

This is not a tax rule we say, I just simply want to add 69% of price for above £10.

Answer (score 2):

My way doing this would be to listen the `catalog_product_prepare_save` event and write a function in the observer.php which sets the price of the product. You can find an illustrative  tutorial on events and observer [here](http://www.pierrefay.com/event-observers-magento-tutorial-howto-105).